# Should I include the same library on different iFrames?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, iframe

I have a simple question. I have a JSP including 4 different iFrames. In my JSP I'm including JQuery UI libraries:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Considering that I need to use them for different reasons in any of my iFrames (I also call methods from one iFrame to another with JQuery syntax), should I include these libraries in any iFrame or just in my JSP and somehow rely on them form my embedded iFrames?
In case how can I use these libraries within my iFrame?

P.S I'm talking in terms of efficiency, reliability, I don't want to include them several times to make my page slower.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use it `window.parent.document` instead of `$`

jQuery is a library on top of JavaScript, not a complete replacement for it. You don't have to replace every last JavaScript expression with something involving $.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to. Using `window.parent` you can obtain a reference to `window.parent.$` or `window.parent.jQuery` inside of your iframes.

So I guess simply saying:

```
var $ = window.parent.$;
```

Would give you access to the already loaded jQuery libraries.